# End a task if the windows form is also terminated through task manager

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a login windows form that pops up when I open MS Access. If the user decides to leave, I have a cancel button that closes the application and MS Access:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

But I also want to add that if the user terminates the windows form, it will also terminate MS Access.

ie., if windowForm terminated, then Application.Exit

Comment: Did you try the Form.Closing event? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx

Comment: I think Closing event is not gonna fire if the user uses End Process. Looks like mission impossible to me

Comment: Look at `OnClosing` Event.

Comment: Try to catch WM_CLOSE or similar WndProc messages. We tried but was not successful. If its an end process from task manager it is not logical to handle it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function to the `FormClosing` event in the Event Properties of your Form or manually:

```
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
```

And then write:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: This line was the key: "this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing); "  I was only using Form1_FormClosing but it wasn't exiting out. Thank you!